# Как отобразить переменную в шаблонизаторе Django

Tags: python, django

В `html` в `scr` отображаю изображения с помощью шаблонизатора (указывая что это статический файл).

На данный момент столкнулся с таким моментом, что мне нужно отобразить изображение по имени, а вот это имя содержится в переменной которую я передаю в html код.

Переменная `a = '02d.png`'

Как мне правильно указать значение переменной в html коде, что бы искало среди статический файлов имя изображение которое храниться в переменной 'a'?

Answer (score -4):

Получилось разобраться. Не сразу понял что, к чему. Если кому-то нужно будет:

```
<img class="block" src="{% static icon "{{ icon }}" %}" height="35" width="35">
```

Comment: Что-то кавычки выглядят неправдоподобно.